# Installing Ubuntu 22.04.3 broke Windows 10 dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, grub-efi

I had Windows 10 co-living with a broken Ubuntu 21 installation. The grub menu was showing both of them, but only Windows was working. There was a time were both worked at the same time, but at some point Ubuntu stopped working.

I decided to install Ubuntu 22.04.3 with the live CD/USB. I wasn't given the option to automatically install alongside Windows 10 updating/replacing the Ubuntu installation that I had, so I selected "other options" and formated my ext4 partition to have Ubuntu 22.04.3 living where the old version was.

The problems start there, cause the installer strongly suggeted me to create an EFI partition - which I didn't have or need with my previous Ubuntu installation.

After trying to get away without doing it, Ubuntu installer complained that the `update-grub` failed. Windows boot was still working at that point, but I didn't achieve to install Ubuntu.

Thus, on a second try, I followed installer recommendation and created an EFI partition for the boot.

The rest is history, now the grub menu doesn't even pop up at start. Ubuntu installer did the same that the comunity have been complaining about Windows installer for years. It took over my PC and now it's the only OS that I can chose to boot.

How can I recover the dual boot without reinstalling Windows? (I don't even know if I could reinstall, god only knows where those CDs and keys are).

I have been googling around and it seems there is hope if you had installed Windows in EFI mode, but I don't think that's my case.

There's a Windows boot partition `sda5` that has these files:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user user   65536 sep 16  2021 BOOTSTAT.DAT
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user user   28648 oct 11 21:59 bootuwf.dll
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user user  101232 oct 11 21:59 bootvhd.dll
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user user 1004400 oct 11 22:00 memtest.exe
```

`sudo fdisk -l` shows this:

```
Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1            2048   1026047   1024000   500M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2         1026048 973766282 972740235 463,8G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       975765504 976769023   1003520   490M 27 Hidden NTFS WinRE
/dev/sda4       973766654 975765503   1998850   976M  5 Extended
/dev/sda5  *    973766656 975765503   1998848   976M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Device          Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1          34     262177     262144  128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sdb2      264192 5036417023 5036152832  2,3T Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdb3  5036417024 5858532258  822115235  392G Linux filesystem
/dev/sdb4  5858533376 5860532223    1998848  976M EFI System
```

Windows is living in `sda2` and Ubuntu in `sdb3`

`sudo os-prober` gives no output

```
$ sudo update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.2.0-35-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-35-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.2.0-26-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-26-generic
Memtest86+ needs a 16-bit boot, that is not available on EFI, exiting
Warning: os-prober will not be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Systems on them will not be added to the GRUB boot configuration.
Check GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER documentation entry.
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
done
```

Comment: First - for the grub menu to appear, add `GRUB_TERMINAL=console` to `/etc/default/grub` and do `sudo update-grub` in terminal.

Comment: That didn't add windows to the grub, I'll add the output to the question, for completeness.

Comment: If you only have one install, the grub menu does not show by default. Or one install in same boot mode.  You have to use escape key with UEFI boot or shift key with BIOS boot. You have newer UEFI hardware and installed Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode which needs an ESP - efi system partition. But have Windows in old BIOS mode on MBR drive. Microsoft required vendors to install in UEFI mode to gpt partitioned drives since 2012, so most systems are UEFI and should have UEFI Windows. Conversion from MBR to gpt will totally erase drive, so have good backups.